# Local HTML file: Can't read local text file because of cross origin eror

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a local HTML page to serve as an interface to view videos I have downloaded to my computer. This file is not part of a server and just exists on my local harddrive. I also saved all the metadata from those videos into one large json(ish) file (It is not correctly formatted as json, each new line is a different json object). I need to load the data from my json file into my html page in order to access the metadata.

```
<script>
    $.get('file://database.json', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
</script>
```

However, as expected I am receiving the cross origin error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///E:/Videos/database.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

I know it is difficult to work around CORS for security reasons but I am looking for a solution that does not require setting up a web server and will work on most browsers without having to launch them with special arguments or change the settings. I don't want to have to create a full application for the viewer because my goal for the viewer was simplicity, compatibility and ease of design.

Is there is a way around this policy or an alternative method I can use to load files into my local HTML page?

**Edit:**

I tested @JasonB's idea of loading the database.json file as a script and it works. However, to get it to work I had to manually add some lines to the file, and format the json properly. I am wondering if there is a way to load the unformatted file as a script and still use its data? Here is the question I asked about formatting my file as a reference:
[Batch File: Append line to file, keeping it wrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829721/batch-file-append-line-to-file-keeping-it-wrapped)

Answer (score 3):

Just put your content into a .js file and link it like any other javascript file and the browser won't have any problem with it.

Comment: While looking through other answers I came across that as a possible solution (I don't think the file even needs to end in .js as long as it is loaded as the src of a script). However, I am not sure how to properly format my file for use as a script. I asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829721/batch-file-append-text-to-file-keeping-it-wrapped

Answer (score 0):

The browser will stop you from requesting things via `file://` as that is potential security issue, even if the file is loaded via `file://`.

An alternative could be to use the non-standard [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) that is available in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge. It lets you store files as well as retrieve them again. I have [a running sample web app here](https://hello-filesystem-api.glitch.me/) and [the code is here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/hello-filesystem-api?path=script.js:1:1).

Note that this won't work out of the box, either as "file://" origins will cause DOMExceptions normally. For Chrome, you can start the browser with the `--allow-file-accom-files` flag to allow access to the FileSystem API from a local HTML file.